# Checkbox - CSS effect not working

Tags: java, css, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a problem that I can not solve. I want to do this effect: Click [`http://codepen.io/siiron/pen/MYXZWg`](http://codepen.io/siiron/pen/MYXZWg)

Passing data from the view to the controller works fine, the data after clicking the checkbox properly subscribe to the list in the IdsDTO. The CSS effect does not work, when you click checkbox, the color does not change to green and visually nothing happens.

Any idea? Thanks!

DTO:

```
public class IdsDTO {

    private List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Integer> getIds() {
        return ids;
    }

    public void setIds(List<Integer> ids) {
        this.ids = ids;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/hall")
public String showHall(){

      IdsDTO idsDTO = new IdsDTO();

      model.addAttribute("idsDTO", idsDTO);      

      return "someHall";
}
```

View:

```
...

<form action="#" th:action="@{/hall}" th:object="${idsDTO}" method="post">
      ...

   <li class="seat">
       <input type="checkbox" id="1A" th:field="*{ids}" th:value="${1}" />
       <label for="1A"></label>
   </li>
   <li class="seat">
       <input type="checkbox" id="1B" th:field="*{ids}" th:value="${2}"  />
       <label for="1B"></label>
   </li>
    ...

</form>
```

**EDIT1:**

My css:

```
.seats {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
.seat {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 14.28571428571429%;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
}
.seat:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 14.28571428571429%;
}
.seat input[type=checkbox] {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.seat input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
  background: #00B70C;
  -webkit-animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-name: rubberBand;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.seat input[type=checkbox]:disabled + label {
  background: #D00000;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.seat input[type=checkbox]:disabled + label:after {
  text-indent: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
}
.seat input[type=checkbox]:disabled + label:hover {
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
.seat label {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 4px 0;
  background: #949494;
  border-radius: 5px;
  animation-duration: 300ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.seat label:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
  top: 1px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.seat label:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0px 2px #5C6AFF;
}
```

I also tried this way:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/hall}" method="post">

   <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1E" th:value="${5}" name="list" />
      <label for="1E">1E</label>
   </li>
   <li class="seat">
      <input type="checkbox" id="1F" th:value="${6}" name="list" />
      <label for="1F">1F</label>
   </li>

</form>
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/hall")
public String showHall(){

      ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

      model.addAttribute("list", list);

  return "someHall";
}
```

and the css effect works, the color changes to green but there is another problem. Only the first of the selected checkboxes is added to the ArrayList, and the next one is not.

**EDIT2**

I solved it this way:

Controller:

```
@GetMapping("/hall")
public String showHall(){

      IdsDTO idsDTO = new IdsDTO();

      model.addAttribute("idsDTO", idsDTO);      

      return "someHall";
}
```

View:

```
...

<form action="#" th:action="@{/hall}" th:object="${idsDTO}" method="post">
      ...

   <li class="seat">
       <input type="checkbox" id="1A" th:value="${1}" name="ids" />
       <label for="1A"></label>
   </li>
   <li class="seat">
       <input type="checkbox" id="1B" th:value="${2}" name="ids" />
       <label for="1B"></label>
   </li>
    ...

</form>
```

Now, everything works as it should!

Comment: Can we see your css?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable your bootstrap and other css files. If problem solved then you've got css override for the checkbox input inside those files.

Comment: When I turn off css files I get standard checkboxes. I edited the post ..

Comment: Can u share the website online? P.s. the controller has nothing do with it.